# How can I remove stop words from a large text file?

Tags: perl, stop-words

I have a billion word corpus which I have collected in a scalar. I have a .regex file that contains all the stop words that I want to eliminate from my data (text).

I don't know how to use this .regex file, so I have made an array and stored all the stop words of the .regex file in my stop word array.

To remove the stop words I do something like this:

```
grep { $scalarText =~ s/\b\Q$_\E\b/ /g } @stopList;
```

This takes a long time to execute. How can I use the .regex file in my Perl script to remove the stop words? Or is there any faster way to remove the stop words?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I imagine what you're doing there is extremely slow, albeit for a couple of reasons. I think you need to process your stopwords regex *before* you build up your string of a billion words from your corpus.

I have no idea what a .regex file is, but I'm going to presume it contains a legal Perl regular expression, something that you can compile using no more than:

```
$stopword_string = `cat foo.regex`;
$stopword_rx     = qr/$stopword_string/;
```

That probably presumes that there's a `(?x)` at the start.

But if your stopword file is a list of lines, you will need to do something more like this:

```
chomp(@stopwords = `cat foo.regex`);

# if each stopword is an independent regex:
$stopword_string = join "|" => @stopwords;

# else if each stopword is a literal
$stopword_string = join "|" => map {quotemeta} @stopwords;

# now compile it (maybe add some qr//OPTS)
$stopword_rx     = qr/\b(?:$stopword_string)\b/;
```

### WARNING

Be *very* careful with `\b`: it's only going to do what you think it does above if the first character in the first word and the last character in the last word is an alphanumunder (a `\w` character).  Otherwise, it will be asserting something you probably don't mean.  If that could be a possibility, you will need to be more specific.  The leading `\b` would need to become `(?:(?<=\A)|(?<=\s))`, and the trailing `\b` would need to become `(?=\s|\z)`.  That's what most people *think* `\b` means, but it really doesn't.

Having done that, you should apply the stopword regex to the corpus as you're reading it in. The best way to do this is **not** to put the stuff into your string in the first place that you'll just need to take out later.

So instead of doing

```
$corpus_text = `cat some-giant-file`;
$corpus_text =~ s/$stopword_rx//g;
```

Instead do

```
my $corpus_path = "/some/path/goes/here";
open(my $corpus_fh, "< :encoding(UTF-8)", $corpus_path)
    || die "$0: couldn't open $corpus_path: $!";

my $corpus_text = q##;

while (<$corpus_fh>) {
    chomp;  # or not
    $corpus_text .= $_ unless /$stopword_rx/;
}

close($corpus_fh)
    || die "$0: couldn't close $corpus_path: $!";
```

That will be much faster than putting stuff in there that you just have to weed out again later.

My use of `cat` above is just a shortcut.  I don't expect you to actually call a program, least of all `cat`, just to read in a single file, unprocessed and unmolested. ☺

Comment: Tip for those reading: nobody sane should use `$arg = \`cat  file\`` , they should use `$arg = File::Slurp::slurp($file) ` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.34/Assemble.pm) to compile a list of Perl regexes into one regex.

Comment: Some of the tricks that module does for reducing common patterns with redundant parts is automatically taken care of for you these days because of the recent trie optimization.  Perl automatically applies the needed cleverness to a set of alternatives with common, constant strings between the choices.  Use `-Mre=debug` to see this in action.

Answer (score 0):

I found a faster way to do it. Saves me around 4 seconds.

```
my $qrstring = '\b(' . (join '|', @stopList) . ')\b';
$scalarText =~ s/$qrstring/ /g;
```

where `stopList` is the array of all my words
and `scalarText` is my whole text.

Can anyone please tell me a faster way if you know any?

Comment: Just pray none of the stop words contains characters which mean something in a regex: you did not use `\Q\E` so Bad Things May Happen

Comment: Don't save the stopword into a group (`$1` in this case): it costs time and memory.  Use a clustering-only (ie, non-capturing) group via `(?:xxx)` as I do in my answer.

Comment: Saves 4 seconds **relative to what**?

Comment: relative to the time I needed to do it earlier which was like 73 seconds

Comment: +1: While the approach is a bit crude (capturing parens, no safeguards against regex metacharacters in`@stopwords`), you've found the right general approach by combining all the stopwords into a single regex instead of searching for them one at a time. See DVK's answer for a more refined way to do this (Regexp::Assemble).

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: unless you have so many alternatives that the optimization isn't used (a *lot*), the built in aho-corasick matching used for |-d fixed strings in 5.10+ will greatly outperform Regexp::Assemble or any of the half dozen similar modules.

Comment: @ysth: Really? Thanks for the correction - I'd heard that alternation handling was better-optimized in newer perls, but had no idea it was *that* much better. Good to know.